# Build a vector from single items in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the numbers: `1 2 3 4` and want to build a vector (or any kind of seq) from them, so I want `[1 2 3 4]`.

As in `(= (__ 1 8 3 4) 8)`, without using `max`.
Here is what I have so far :

`(= (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) 1 8 3 4) 8)`

But I get an `ArityException`, and therefore want to build a `vector` of `[1 8 3 4]`.

How can I convert the single numbers to be items of a collection ?

Comment: Where are these numbers? In your head? In some data structure?

Comment: they are arguments of a function: `(= (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) 1 8 3 4) 8)`. It should find out the max value of args, without using `max`. But `reduce` needs them as a collection.

Comment: so the evaluation of the above should return `true`

Comment: Are you talking about `1 8 3 4`? Just write that as `[1 8 3 4]`.

Comment: I cant rewrite them, they are given

Comment: You're really not explaining your problem very well at all. Given by what? Or who? Why? How are they "given"?

Comment: https://www.4clojure.com/problem/38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`vector`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vector) :

```
;; create a vector the long way
user=> (vector 1 2 3 4)
```

Note that if you are talking about hardcoded values, the advantage of having code as data is that you can represent them exactly like that in your code :

```
;; this is code, equivalent to the code above
[1 2 3 4]
```

If you are talking about generating a sequence of numbers, have a look at [`range`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/range) :

```
user=> (range 1 5)
(1 2 3 4)
```

[`vec`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec) will take a collection and turn into a vector :

```
user=> (vec (range 1 5))
[1 2 3 4]
```

Taking into account your comment :

```
user=> (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) (vector 1 8 3 4))
8

user=> (= (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) (vector 1 8 3 4)) 8)
true
```

But as you surely know, you could use [`max`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max) :

```
user=> (max 1 2 3 4)
4
user=> (apply max [1 2 3 4])
4
```

If you really wish not to use `max`, a concise way of getting the max would be :
    user=> (last (sort [1 2 3 4]))
    4

Or as an anonymous function, using a threading macro :

```
user=> #(-> % sort last) ;; % stand for all arguments, as a sequence
4
```

Comment: I'm not sure i am using it correctly `#(-> $& sort last)`? i get: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: $& in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)` if i do: `(#(-> $& sort last) 1 2 3)` or `(#(-> $& sort last) [1 2 3])`

Comment: Sorting to obtain the max is inefficient. `max` is linear, sorting is n (log n). If `max` didn't exist you might do it in the repl as a quick hack, but other than that you'd never want a worse than linear search for a maximum or minimum value in a program.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i am sorry Pointy, i was just a bit in hurry. This was the original question: `(= (__ 1 8 3 4) 8)` and i was trying to find out the maximum value amongst the numbers without using `max`. I thought i use`reduce` which by the way takes a collection as argument. Now i ended up filling the blank like this: `(= ((fn [& x]
      (let [arg (apply vector x)]
         (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) arg)))
    1 2 3 4 8) 8)`. I used destructuring and it works `true` (although maybe not looking elegant!)

Comment: you can just do `(= ((fn [& xs] (reduce #(if (< %1 %2) %2 %1) xs)) 1 2 3 4 8) 8)`